# Spring-websocket-run-errors-on-cloudfoundry-Pivotal-Web-Services

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-websocket

**I have solved this issue, this code help me auto-detect server is https or http. Then Javascript just create correct link SockJS to subcribe to server Web-socket.**

Code as below:

```
var protocol = location.protocol;
var hostname = location.hostname;
var port = location.port;
var url_prefix = protocol + "//" + hostname + (port === '' ? '' : ':' + port) + contextPath;
var sock = new SockJS(url_prefix + '/connectsocket');
```

---

**Spring websocket run ok on localhost:**

```
var socket = new SockJS('http: //localhost:9091/connect/sockjs');
```

**Spring websocket run errors on bics.cfapps.io:**

```
var socket = new SockJS('http: //bics.cfapps.io/connect/sockjs');
```

*Error message console.log*:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://bics.cfapps.io/connect/sockjs/376/7o5_41y7/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

sockjs-0.3.4.js:807 POST http: //bics.cfapps.io/connect/sockjs/376/colrrwci/xhr_streaming 500 (Internal Server Error)

Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

**Add port 4443 but it stills errors on bics.cfapps.io:**

```
var socket = new SockJS('http: //bics.cfapps.io:4443/connect/sockjs');
```

*Error message console.log*:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: //bics.cfapps.io:4443/connect/sockjs/info. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Origin 'http: //bics.cfapps.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 408.

Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

**Add port 4443 & ws but it stills errors on bics.cfapps.io:**

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://bics.cfapps.io:4443/connect/sockjs');
```

*Error message console.log*:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://bics.cfapps.io:4443/connect/sockjs' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 408

Whoops! Lost connection to ws://bics.cfapps.io:4443/connect/sockjs
```

**My code configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/bics");
    }
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/connect/sockjs").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your websocket configuration and logs. Does connection was made from same origin?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan please see my update question. My project runs ok on my local, but it runs error on cloudfoundry ... errors as I describe above

Comment: The same issue is coming with me, have you found anything

Comment: Read this? http://docs.run.pivotal.io/release-notes/? You need wss: not ws:

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing out that answer given by gregturn in the comments is correct:

PWS does **not** support normal websockets via `ws:` but only secure websockets via `wss:`.  Additionally, they work on the non-standard port 4443.

See [PWS release notes June 2016](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/release-notes/)